# MikroTik two network NAT to one network

Tags: nat

**This is my network:**

**First Floor**    (**192.168.1.X**\24)  -------> **MikroTik**
**Second Floor**   (**192.168.2.X**\24)  ---> **MikroTik**

**MikroTik** --------------------------------> **PC** (**10.X.X.X**\8)

In *First* and *Second Floor*, I have **AP** that clients with an IP Address on **192.168.1.X**\24 and **192.168.2.X**\24 ranges connected to the network.

I wanna **NAT** this two ranges to **10.X.X.X**\8 (a PC which connected to ether3). The PC's IP address is **10.0.0.1**\8.

Comment: `/ip address add address=10.0.0.2/8 interface=ether3 network=10.0.0.0` + `/ip firewall nat add action=masquerade chain=srcnat out-interface=ether3` + `/ip route add distance=1 gateway=10.0.0.1`

Comment: @Akina I'm sorry. The post edited.